# Do I need to have recaptcha v3 script on all pages to calculate right score

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I am using recaptch v3 token generate method only on my signup & login page. For this I am using following mentioned code which generates a token and embed it into my login or signup form for sending it to server:

```
grecaptcha.ready(function () {
     grecaptcha.execute('XXXXXXXXXX', {action: 'submit'}).then(function (token) {
         //Add token in signup/login form
     });
});
```

My Question is - For generating a token that could provide me an accurate result, do I need to add recaptcha script like below on all pages of website? Or I can add this script and above mentioned code only on signup or login page.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=XXXXXXXXXX"></script>
```